# Как узнать программно какие наборы языков (voice data/voice sets) имеются (установлены) на телефоне (в Google TTS voice data)?

Tags: android, android-studio, tts, text-to-speech, синтезатор-речи

Как узнать программно какие наборы языков (voice data/voice sets) имеются (установлены) на телефоне (в **Google TTS voice data**)?

Т.е. нужно определить имеется или отсутствует тот или иной языковой набор для синтезатора речи в телефоне и в случае его отсутствия предложить установить его

*( Settings->Language & Input>Text-to-speech output->Google Text-to-speech Engine>Setting>Install voice data>Choose language and install )*

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872702/get-available-locales-for-text-to-speech-tts)

Comment: Спасибо, TimurVI !